# Faster method to append BigQuery data to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a little (actually big one) with appending data from BigQuery to a dataframe. The query itself takes approximately 20 seconds, but the entire run of the script below takes on 10 minutes.

```
groups = []
current_group = []
current_sum = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if current_sum + row['storeid'] <= 1000:
        current_group.append(row['tenantId'])
        current_sum += row['storeid']
    else:
        groups.append(current_group)
        current_group = [row['tenantId']]
        current_sum = row['storeid']

groups.append(current_group)
print(len(groups))

project1 = 'project'

timeline_data = []
for i in range(len(groups)):
    store_selection_t =  tenant_stores[tenant_stores.tenantId.isin(groups[i])]
    store_selection = list(set(store_selection_t.storeid))
    query = f"""
    WITH LatestEntries AS (
      SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY barcode ORDER BY Date(timestamp) DESC) AS row_num
      FROM
        `{project1}.dataset.table`
    )
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      LatestEntries
    WHERE
      row_num = 1
    and storeid IN (@store_selection)
    """

    random_store_selection_str = ",".join(["'{}'".format(value) for value in store_selection])
    query = query.replace("@store_selection", random_store_selection_str)

    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    labels_shifted_aggregated = client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
    timeline_data.append(labels_shifted_aggregated)

timeline_data = pd.concat(timeline_data)
```

As the query itself takes pratically no time and returns a table with 32 million rows, I am certain the problem is with this step:

```
timeline = client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
timeline_data.append(labels_shifted_aggregated)
```

I tried using solutions suggested by `ChatGPT` involving `BigQueryReadClient` from `from google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1 import BigQueryReadClient` but the suggested solutions are pure gibberish.

Are there alternatives to the `.to_dataframe()`-method?

Comment: I'm not following the code.  What is "labels_shifted_aggregated" and how does that relate to "timeline".  Where is your python code running?   I hear you say that you are downloading 32M rows ... how big is a row?  Do you actually need to return all the columns?   I'd run a test to see how long it takes to retrieve the data into your Python environment.   You say the run of the script takes 10 minutes ... how many times round the loop does it go?  I'd focus on debugging ONE instance and then work up from there.

Comment: @Kolban: ```labels_shifted_aggregated``` is the result of the query for each group (there are 4 groups, thus the loop goes for times). ```timeline``` is the result of the 4 ```label_shifted_aggreagated``` obtained in each run. The code is running in VS Code for the moment but will be running on GCP, eventually. 

Thanks for your advice about debugging.

Comment: How are you measuring query time?  Do you have pyarrow installed and are you using the latest version of client libraries?  Id suggest at least a trial run on GCP to rule out networking bandwidth and host CPU.  To_datafeame should be close to optimal